# Как получить область видимости с одной функции в другую?

Tags: javascript

Как получить область видимости[scope] LexicalEnvironment с одной функции в другую?

```js
function number() {
  var a=5;
  var b=5;
  var c=5
}
number();

function summa() {

  return a+b+c;
}
var d = summa();
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Ни как. переменные доступны только внутри функции или в замыканиях, ей созданных

Comment: а как через замыкания сделать? может через call можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если очень хочется, то можно вот так. Главное не потерять `new`, иначе `this` станет `window` и переменные объявятся как глобальные

```js
function number() {
  this.a=5;
  this.b=5;
  this.c=5
  return this;
}

function summa() {
  return this.a+this.b+this.c;
}

console.log(summa.call(new number()));
```

Comment: спасибо это и хотел увидеть, надо все таки найти время и про них почитать

Comment: @Starbax Ну вообще то тут получаются глобальные переменные. После выполнения этого скрипта выведите скажем `console.log(a)` ... А все потому, что при вызове `number()` в качестве this у него оказывается глобальный объект (в браузерах это window (в чем легко убедится посмотреть свойства window.a))

Comment: Да, так они не глобальные, но в объекте. А это уже не LexicalEnvironment из вопроса. Хотя очень может быть, что ТС объект вполне устроит, ибо другого выхода все равно нет

Comment: я не присмотрелся про this, а как тогда сделать как в вопросе без this?

Comment: this - это и есть  обращение к `LexicalEnvironment `, без него обращение будет к window - глобальной области видимости

Comment: а как можно еще сделать чтобы не изменять значения number() функции? когда например хочешь получить несколько значений из одной функции в другую не изменяя первую

Comment: или только через this привязка?

Comment: Передать аргументы `function summa(a,b,c) {
  return a+b+c;
}`